# Como evitar que el formulario se mande si tengo radiobuttons en NO

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, formularios, web

Estoy haciendo un formulario de newsletter,
tengo 4 opciones todas tienen Si y No
ahora quiero evitar que el form se mande si todo está en NO

este es mi código, lo intente con Js pero no me salió.
Muchas gracias

```html
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->

<style type="text/css">
 #mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
 /* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
    We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
     tr,th,td{
      padding-left: : 15px;
      padding-right: 15px;
    
     }
     th{
      text-align: center;
     }
     p{
      line-height: 3;
     }
     table{}
     input{
      text-align: center;
     }
</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="hqa.php" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" validate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
 
<div class="mc-field-group input-group">
    <table width=100% align="center" style="border-spacing: 20px">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="1" width="300" style="border-color: #faf8f8" bgcolor=#faf8f8>
          <input type="radio" value="Si" name="MMERGE1" id="mce-MMERGE1-0" checked> 
          <label for="mce-MMERGE1-0"> Si</label>  
          <input type="radio" value="No" name="MMERGE1" id="mce-MMERGE1-1"> 
          <label for="mce-MMERGE1-1"> No</label>
        </td>
        <td align="center" colspan="1" width="300" style="border-color: #faf8f8" bgcolor=#faf8f8>
           <input type="radio" value="Si" name="MMERGE2" id="mce-MMERGE2-0" checked> 
           <label for="mce-MMERGE2-0">Si</label> 
           <input type="radio" value="No" name="MMERGE2" id="mce-MMERGE2-1"> 
           <label for="mce-MMERGE2-1">No</label>
        </td>
        <td align="center" colspan="1" width="300" style="border-color: #faf8f8" bgcolor=#faf8f8>
              <input type="radio" value="Si" name="MMERGE3" id="mce-MMERGE3-0" checked> 
              <label for="mce-MMERGE3-0">Si</label> 
              <input type="radio" value="No" name="MMERGE3" id="mce-MMERGE3-1"> 
              <label for="mce-MMERGE3-1">No</label>
        </td>
        <td align="center" colspan="1" width="300" style="border-color: #faf8f8" bgcolor=#faf8f8>
           <input type="radio" value="Si" name="MMERGE4" id="mce-MMERGE4-0" checked> 
           <label for="mce-MMERGE4-0">Si</label> 
           <input type="radio" value="No" name="MMERGE4" id="mce-MMERGE4-1"> 
           <label for="mce-MMERGE4-1">No</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table> 
   

</div>

 <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
  <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
  <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
 </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
  <h3 align="center">Suscríbete a nuestro Newsletter</h3>
<div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk"></div>
<div class="mc-field-group" align="center">
  <input style="width: 400px" align="center" type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Ingresa tu correo electrónico">
</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_adc1b7090103e09e24a7d0365_edeab16967" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear" align="center">
      <br>
      <br><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js">
        $("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").on('submit', function (evt) {

            if (!$("#mce-MMERGE1-1").is(':checked') && 
!$("mce-MMERGE2-1").is(':checked') && !$("#mce-MMERGE3-1").is(':checked') && !$("#mce-MMERGE4-1").is(':checked')) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                alert('No has marcado un Sí');
            }
        });
    </script>
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Lo quieres hacer con JavaScript forzosamente? ¿Osea en el lado del cliente? Si quisieras hacerlo del lado del servidor y hacer una validación podrías utilizar un documento PHP "enmedio" de la página con el formulario y la página donde se procesan las variables, de modo que si los 4 valores son `NO` te redireccione a la primera página con un mensaje de error.

Comment: Es que como es un embed de mailchimp no me permite usar un intermedio, ya lo intente y no jalo :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

podrías capturar el evento change de todos los radios y si todos los valores de los radios son "No" que te des-habilite el boton submit o de lo contrario que lo habilite.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('input[type=radio][name=MMERGE1],input[type=radio][name=MMERGE2],input[type=radio][name=MMERGE3],input[type=radio][name=MMERGE4]').change(function () {
    
    
                    if ($("input[name='MMERGE1']:checked").val() == 'No' && $("input[name='MMERGE2']:checked").val() == 'No' && $("input[name='MMERGE3']:checked").val() == 'No' && $("input[name='MMERGE4']:checked").val() == 'No') {
                        $("#mc-embedded-subscribe").attr('disabled','disabled');
                    }
                    else  {
                        $("#mc-embedded-subscribe").removeAttr('disabled','disabled');
                    }
   
                });
            });
    
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías validar el envío usando `return` en vez de `preventDefault()` de la siguiente manera:

```js
$("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").on('submit', function () {
    if ($("#mce-MMERGE1-1").is(':checked') && $("#mce-MMERGE2-1").is(':checked') && $("#mce-MMERGE3-1").is(':checked') && $("#mce-MMERGE4-1").is(':checked')) {   
        alert('No has marcado un Sí');

        return false;;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
    <form action="hqa.php" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" validate>
        <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
    
            <div class="mc-field-group input-group">
                <table width=100% align="center" style="border-spacing: 20px">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" colspan="1" width="300" style="border-color: #faf8f8" bgcolor=#faf8f8>
                            <input type="radio" value="Si" name="MMERGE1" id="mce-MMERGE1-0" checked> 
                            <label for="mce-MMERGE1-0"> Si</label>  
                            <input type="radio" value="No" name="MMERGE1" id="mce-MMERGE1-1"> 
                            <label for="mce-MMERGE1-1"> No</label>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center" colspan="1" width="300" style="border-color: #faf8f8" bgcolor=#faf8f8>
                            <input type="radio" value="Si" name="MMERGE2" id="mce-MMERGE2-0" checked> 
                            <label for="mce-MMERGE2-0">Si</label> 
                            <input type="radio" value="No" name="MMERGE2" id="mce-MMERGE2-1"> 
                            <label for="mce-MMERGE2-1">No</label>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center" colspan="1" width="300" style="border-color: #faf8f8" bgcolor=#faf8f8>
                            <input type="radio" value="Si" name="MMERGE3" id="mce-MMERGE3-0" checked> 
                            <label for="mce-MMERGE3-0">Si</label> 
                            <input type="radio" value="No" name="MMERGE3" id="mce-MMERGE3-1"> 
                            <label for="mce-MMERGE3-1">No</label>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center" colspan="1" width="300" style="border-color: #faf8f8" bgcolor=#faf8f8>
                            <input type="radio" value="Si" name="MMERGE4" id="mce-MMERGE4-0" checked> 
                            <label for="mce-MMERGE4-0">Si</label> 
                            <input type="radio" value="No" name="MMERGE4" id="mce-MMERGE4-1"> 
                            <label for="mce-MMERGE4-1">No</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table> 
            </div>

            <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
                <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
                <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
            </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
            <h3 align="center">Suscríbete a nuestro Newsletter</h3>
            <div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk"></div>
            <div class="mc-field-group" align="center">
                <input style="width: 400px" align="center" type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Ingresa tu correo electrónico">
            </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_adc1b7090103e09e24a7d0365_edeab16967" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
            <div class="clear" align="center">
                <br>
                <br><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias @Jean Carlo es exactamente lo que buscaba y funciono